# NSUserDefault data cannot save if forced to close application. Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, synchronize

Codes seems long, but the idea is simple. First in the refreshResult(), get the data from NSUserDefaults (tempArray), then append the data loaded from server to tempArray, last save the tempArray back to NSUserDefaults. Second in the loadChat(), get the data from NSUserDefaults and use the data to create the chat view. Everything works perfect when I refresh result, I can see the message and image in the chat view. However, when I force to turn off the application and reopen the application again, the data just loaded in refresh result disappear. Really can't find out why.

**UPDATE**

I am pretty sure objects! is not empty as I use three prints: "1", "2", "3".
Real case of what it prints, I loadChat first before refreshResult as refreshResult only be called when there is a new message

```
// loadChat before refresh
3: 59
3: 59
3: 39
3: 21
// send a message from another phone
1: 59
1: 59
1: 39
1: 21
2: 60
2: 60
2: 40
2: 21
// force to close the application(double click home button and swipe up) 
// then open the app again
3: 59
3: 59
3: 39
3: 21



func refreshResult() {
    //**empty the messageArray, senderArray and photoArray
    ...
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects! {
            self.senderArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
            self.messageArray.append(object.objectForKey("message") as? String)
            if object.objectForKey("photo") != nil {
                if let converyPFFile = object.objectForKey("photo") as? PFFile{
                    let temp = try! converyPFFile.getData()
                    let image = UIImage(data: temp)!
                    self.photoArray.append(image)
                }
            } else {
                self.photoArray.append(nil)
            }
            if object.objectForKey("sender") as! String == self.userProfileName {
                object.setObject(true, forKey: "senderDownloaded")
            } else {
                object.setObject(true, forKey: "otherDownloaded")
            }
            object.saveInBackground()
        }

        if objects!.count != 0 {
            var tempLocalNameArray = [String]()
            var tempLocalIsStringArray = [Bool]()
            var tempLocalMessageArray = [String]()
            var tempLocalImageArray = [NSData]()

            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NameArray") != nil {
                tempLocalNameArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NameArray") as! [String]
            }
            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("IsStringArray") != nil {
                tempLocalIsStringArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("IsStringArray") as! [Bool]
            }
            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MessageArray") != nil {
                tempLocalMessageArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MessageArray") as! [String]
            }
            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageArray") != nil {
                tempLocalImageArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageArray") as! [NSData]
            }

            print("1: \(tempLocalNameArray.count)")
            print("1: \(tempLocalIsStringArray.count)")
            print("1: \(tempLocalMessageArray.count)")
            print("1: \(tempLocalImageArray.count)")

            for i in 0 ..< self.senderArray.count {
                tempLocalNameArray.append(self.senderArray[i])
                if self.messageArray[i] != nil {
                    tempLocalIsStringArray.append(true)
                    tempLocalMessageArray.append(self.messageArray[i]!)
                } else {
                    tempLocalIsStringArray.append(false)
                    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.photoArray[i]!)
                    tempLocalImageArray.append(pngImageData!)
                }
            }

            print("2: \(tempLocalNameArray.count)")
            print("2: \(tempLocalIsStringArray.count)")
            print("2: \(tempLocalMessageArray.count)")
            print("2: \(tempLocalImageArray.count)")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tempLocalNameArray, forKey: "NameArray")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tempLocalIsStringArray, forKey: "IsStringArray")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tempLocalMessageArray, forKey: "MessageArray")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tempLocalImageArray, forKey: "ImageArray")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        }

        self.loadChat()
    }
}


func loadChat() {
    var tempLocalNameArray = [String]()
    var tempLocalIsStringArray = [Bool]()
    var tempLocalMessageArray = [String]()
    var tempLocalImageArray = [NSData]()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NameArray") != nil {
        tempLocalNameArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NameArray") as! [String]
    }
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("IsStringArray") != nil {
        tempLocalIsStringArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("IsStringArray")! as! [Bool]
    }
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MessageArray") != nil {
        tempLocalMessageArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MessageArray")! as! [String]
    }
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageArray") != nil {
        tempLocalImageArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageArray")! as! [NSData]
    }

    print("3: \(tempLocalNameArray.count)")
    print("3: \(tempLocalIsStringArray.count)")
    print("3: \(tempLocalMessageArray.count)")
    print("3: \(tempLocalImageArray.count)")

//**use the tempLocalNameArray, tempLocalIsStringArray, tempLocalMessageArray and tempLocalImageArray to create a chat view.
```

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with emphasis on the ***M***.

Answer (score 0):

you're only grabbing the objects from the `NSUserDefaults` if `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` returns objects.  Without seeing any other parts of your code, I'd add some `print` statements to see if `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` returns any objects or not.  If it does return objects, definitely step through the rest of the function with the debugger, with more `print` statements to check the values of `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("NameArray")`, etc.  Definitely will cue you in.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does return objects. Please see my update. Thank you for your time.

Comment: then more code should be shared, because its not clear what calls `refreshResult()` in the first place